# Grails - Spring Security Core onAuthenticationSuccess

Tags: grails, spring-security

I have a form that allows a user to either login or register.

When the user lands on the page containing the form, the request is saved in a RequestCache object (I'm using Spring Security).

In the case that the user decides to register, I want to mimic the behavior of the Spring Security onAuthenticationSuccess code, where the user is redirected to whatever page they were trying to get to before logging in (or, in my case, before registering).

To accomplish that, I added the following code to the RegistrationController:

```
authenticationSuccessHandler.onAuthenticationSuccess(request, response, springSecurityService.authentication)
```

My question is, is this a reasonable approach to handle the on registration success use case? Am I doing enough?

Comment: Usually after registration we should take user to landing page of our application. As he is new one it's not useful to redirect him to the URL which he typed manually in the address bar.

Comment: I have a use case where users receive a link to a specific page. If the user is a new user, I'd like to send them to that page after registering, instead of sending them to the landing page.

Answer (score 0):

Best way would be to keep a link to the original requested URL in a hidden formitem on the registration page and redirect after registration. Try to keep the security layer as simple and close to the original intend as possible.